# fill list of data from datasource in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need file this model `oldDataSource: Array<any> = [];` by value of the datasource .

i try to use this code :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSourceInit();
}

dataSourceInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new DefaultScoreCoinDataSource(this.defaultScorService);
    this.dataSource.loadDefaultScoreCoins(1, this.pageSize, this.filters);
}

private loadDataSource(): void {
    this.dataSource.loadDefaultScoreCoins(
        this.paginator.pageIndex + 1,
        this.paginator.pageSize,
        this.filters
    );
}


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.oldDataSource = this.dataSource['defualtScoreSubject'].value;
}
```

but it's not worked for me and it not fill the `this.oldDataSource` but it when the run `ngAfterViewInit` until datasource not fill becuase he must go to server and get response have many time , for this reason `this.oldDataSource` not fill with value and show null .

How can i fill `this.oldDataSource` with datasource value?

Answer (score 2):

For one, the name in your bracketed property-accessor is probably misspelled ('defualtScoreSubject' should be 'defaultScoreSubject').

More broadly, the way you're fetching data appears unconventional for Angular. I'd suggest writing your data source as a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) that returns Observables. Then subscribe to the observable to handle your data, or pass the observable directly to the template with [async pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). Learn more and [compare the two techniques](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-question-rxjs-subscribe-vs-async-pipe-in-component-templates-c956c8c0c794) to decide how you want to do it.